# NSTextField and NSTouchbar

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am implementing touchbar functionalities.
I want a specific touchbar to be displayed when editing an `NSTextField`.

I have tried to both methods :

- set a touchbar using `touchbar` property :

```swift
field.touchBar = myTouchBar
```

- and subclassing `NSTextField` to override `makeTouchBar()` function :

```swift
class MyTextField: NSTextField
{
   override func makeTouchBar(){return myTouchBar}
}
```

Both methods show an empty touchbar when editing the field. Changing the `isAutomaticTextCompletionEnabled` and `allowsCharacterPickerTouchBarItem` properties does not change it - just making the corresponding buttons appear.

Doing exactly the same thing with an `NSTextView` - or many other type of `NSView`, however, works perfectly well.

Do you know if it is possible to have a custom toolbar when editing an `NSTextField`?

Comment: The `NSTextField` is not the first responder. See [Text Fields, Text Views, and the Field Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Willeke's answer, I have been able to find the solution. It is quite tricky, however :

- First, subclass `NSTextField` to keep another `NSTouchBar` :

```swift
class MyTextField: NSTextField
{
    private var innerTouchBar: Any?
    var editor: NSText?

    @available(OSX 10.12.2, *)
    func setTouchBar(_ touchBar: NSTouchBar?)
    {
        innerTouchBar = touchBar
    }

    @available(OSX 10.12.2, *)
    func getTouchBar() -> NSTouchBar?
    {
        innerTouchBar as? NSTouchBar
    }
}
```

- Then, subclass `NSTextView` to use a provided `NSTouchBar` :

```swift
@available(OSX 10.12.2, *)
class MyTextView: NSTextView
{
    private var innerTouchBar: NSTouchBar?

    convenience init(touchBar: NSTouchBar?)
    {
        self.init()
        innerTouchBar = touchBar
    }

    override func makeTouchBar() -> NSTouchBar?
    {
        innerTouchBar
    }
}
```

- When the `NSWindowController` gets asked for the `NSTextView` of the `NSTextField`, then create a custom `NSTextView` with the `innerTouchBar` of the `NSTextField` :

```swift
extension MyWindowController
{
    func windowWillReturnFieldEditor(_ sender: NSWindow, to client: Any?) -> Any?
    {
        if #available(OSX 10.12.2, *)
        {
             if let field = client as? MyTextField
            {
                if field.editor == nil
                {
                    field.editor = SFTextView(touchBar: field.getTouchBar())
                    field.editor?.isFieldEditor = true
                }
                return field.editor
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }
}
```

- Of course, do not forget to use `MyTextField` instead of `NSTextField` in the XIB or in your code, and to call the `setTouchBar(_:)` function first thing after creation.

### Explanation

Every `NSTextField` has an underlying `NSTextView`, which is in fact the firstResponder, and the object whose touchBar is displayed. We cannot access the underlying `NSTextView` directly from `NSTextField`. Instead, the `NSTextField` asks the `NWindowController` which `NSTextView` to use. So when this happens, in `windowWillReturnFieldEditor(_:,to:)` of `NSWindowController`, we have to return a custom `NSTextView`with the correct touchBar.
I think this can apply to other things than touchBar...